# Startup Script for Refreshing Screen Settings

Tags: linux, display, display-settings

I am running a Linux Mint 17.3 machine with a DVI and USB (DVI-to-USB) monitor connection plugged in to the same desktop.  Upon booting up, I get strange display misalignment that I found out was due to the USB connection - half of one screen is scrunched up on one of the monitors.  However, if I simply go into Settings -> Display and click "Apply" without making any changes, the display problem goes away.

Is there some sort of command that I can add to a startup script in /etc/init.d/ or in a crontab command that will automatically apply/refresh monitor settings in this way for me at startup?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution, which works great, was to do the following:

1. Create a startup.sh file in my home directory `~/` (that way I can port it over during a backup of files later if you wish) with the following command saved in it:

   `pkill -HUP "cinnamon --replace"`
2. Open a terminal session, type `crontab -e` to enter the crontab file, and enter the following and save it:

   `@reboot /home/donkey/startup.sh`
3. Reboot the computer and note that on every boot up now, the cinnamon session refreshes and removes the bootup bugs on the monitors I am using, making the resolution span perfectly across all monitors.

Hooray :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try telling `xrandr` to set the display to its automatic settings.

```
xrandr --output XXXXX --auto
```

Run `xrandr` on its own to get all valid output names.

Comment: This works well if I know what the monitor names are.  Unfortunately I disconnect different monitors with different connection types, so what will be 'DVI-1' one day will be 'USB-0-1' another day... which makes this solution not as effective.  Thanks all the same :)

Comment: So then parse the output of `xrandr` to get what the active displays are. It's a computer, make it do what it's good at.

Comment: Yep, that would work as well.  I'm too lazy, but I learned a lot about xrandr from investigating your answer, so thanks a bunch.